# Technical Issue : replace names with " find "

Tags: command-line, find

I am trying to replace names in the files from (token) to ( take )  by using :

```
find ./ -type f -readable - writable -exec sed -i "s/token/take/g" {} \;
```

but I got this :

```
find: paths must precede expression: `-'
```

what's the problem ? and how can we solve it ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra space between `-` and `writable`

So the correct command is:

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/token/take/g" {} \;
```